# Tree ID request

Tags: species-identification, trees

We have a small tree (more like a shrub) in our village in North Eastern Anatolia, and it is known for its local name which is not Turkish. Even worse, I don't know which language it is, but most likely there are Armenian, Georgian, maybe Russian influences in the regions' language. So I cannot find it in literature.

It is spelled as "syr-sun-syllic". Its fruit has a name too, that is pronounced like "lyllic". It gives red and round fruits in autumn, which are edible.

Here are some photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

It is said to be "lonicera iberica" by http://nhm.co.uk, which has edible fruits.

Comment: In addition, it gives fruits in autumn.

Comment: could you describe the flowers and the fruit? the way the leaves grow reminds me of honeysuckle (Lonicera).

Comment: What's the local name?

Comment: It is spelled as "syr-sun-syllic". Its fruit has a name too, that is pronounced like "lyllic". Our villages have more words that are not Turkish. Even the villages called with their non turkish old names by the peasents. I think probable languages affected us are armenian, georgian, maybe russian etc.

Comment: Nope it is probably not a honeysuckle.

Comment: It has a layered trunk and one can easily tear them off by hand.

Comment: The leaves are indeed similar to lonicera (honeysuckle). How do the flowers and fruit look? What color, size and shape do they have? Do they grow solitary or in groups? Any info might help (and a picture would be fantastic).

Comment: Its fruits are small red rounds and are eatable.

Comment: Interesting. Red and round rules out *Eucalyptus*, that does have opposite-leaves and a peeling bark. Honeysuckle has red and round fruits but afaik they are not edible.

Comment: It is said to be lonicera iberica by nhm.co.uk, which has edible fruits.

Comment: @AhmedBilâl You should post this as an answer. Posting answers to your own questions (if you find them) is encouraged in the StackExchange network. Then your questions is also removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

It is said to be lonicera iberica by nhm.co.uk, which has edible fruits.

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand this answer and add a picture of the plant. Additionally it is always good to not give just a one-line answer but one, that stands on its own and explains stuff.